# Python, функция иногда выдает none

Tags: python

Решил попытаться написать игру Коровы и Быки на Питоне. Написал первую функцию которая должна рандомить массив из трех чисел. Проверяя функцию заметил что иногда функция выдаёт "none". Понятия не имею с чем это может быть связано.

P.S. Изначально код был меньше, было if secretNum[0] == ([secretNum[1] or secretNum[2]) и еще одна подобная строка для проверки второго элемента массива. Поменял, думая что это поможет решить проблему, не помогло)

Вот код

```
#Импорт нужных модулей
import random

#Функция присваивания секретного числа
def setNum():
    secretNum = []
    secretNumSet = random.randint(100,999)
    #Цикл разделяющий число int на массив
    for i in str(secretNumSet):
           secretNum.append(i)
    #Проверка числа на одиннаковые цифры. Т.е. не равна ли первая цифра второй и т.д. Нужно для правильного числа по правилам игры 
    if secretNum[0] == secretNum[1]:
        setNum()
    elif secretNum[0] == secretNum[2]:
        setNum()
    elif secretNum[1] == secretNum[0]:
        setNum()
    elif secretNum[1] == secretNum[2]:
        setNum()
    else:
        return secretNum    #Если всё нормально, функция возвращает массив secretNum

#Присваивание массива secretNum через функцию setNum()
secretNum = setNum()
print(secretNum)#Удалить, написал для проверки правильности кода
```

Comment: Странные проверки. `if secretNum[0] == secretNum[1]:` ... `elif secretNum[1] == secretNum[0]:`. Что там вообще должно проверяться? Есть ли одинаковые цифры? Если да, то можно обойтись одной проверкой: `if len(set(secretNum)) < len(secretNum)` - `True`, если есть повторяющиеся элементы.

Comment: Будет выдавать none всегда, когда в первой попытке в числе будут две одинаковые цифры. Читайте про рекурсию.

Comment: А разве при setNum() не должно рандомиться новое число и проверяться оно? Или это связано с тем что я сразу присваиваю secretNum через функцию?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, что вы хотели использовать рекурсию, тогда нужно `setNum()` внутри каждого `(el)if` заменить на `return setNum()`.

```
#Функция присваивания секретного числа
def setNum():
    secretNum = []
    secretNumSet = random.randint(100,999)
    #Цикл разделяющий число int на массив
    for i in str(secretNumSet):
           secretNum.append(i)
    #Проверка числа на одиннаковые цифры. Т.е. не равна ли первая цифра второй и т.д. Нужно для правильного числа по правилам игры 
    if secretNum[0] == secretNum[1]:
        return setNum()
    elif secretNum[0] == secretNum[2]:
        return setNum()
    elif secretNum[1] == secretNum[0]:
        return setNum()
    elif secretNum[1] == secretNum[2]:
        return setNum()
    else:
        return secretNum    #Если всё нормально, функция возвращает массив secretNum
```

Однако, лучше использовать такой код, если целью является именно рекурсивная функция:

```
def setNum():
    secretNumSet = random.randint(100, 999)
    secretNum = [i for i in str(secretNumSet)]  # число int на массив
    if len(set(secretNum)) == len(secretNum):
        return secretNum
    return setNum()
```

Или такой код, если рекурсивная функция целью не является:

```
def setNum():
    while True:
        secretNumSet = random.randint(100, 999)
        secretNum = [i for i in str(secretNumSet)]  # число int на массив
        if len(set(secretNum)) == len(secretNum):
            break
    return secretNum
```

Comment: Да думал через рекурсию, толком о ней не знаю. Спасибо большое. Пошел учить рекурсию)

Comment: @GovnoKoder Код генерации числа, кстати, лучше переписать, чтобы оно именно генерировало число по правилу, а не генерировало, пока "случайно не получится нужное".